# UniversalBot class not exists in botbuilder package in microsoft bot service SDKv.4

Tags: node.js, authentication, botframework, azure-bot-service

**UniversalBot** and **ChatConnector** class does not exists under **botbuilder** package in the microsoft bot framework **SDK v4**

I want to access the variable **session.message.sourceEvent.tenant.id** in microsoft bot framework **SDK v4.0**.

To access that we would need to create instance for **UniversalBot** class.

But I couldn't find under **UniversalBot** under **botbuilder** package in the microsoft bot framework **SDK v4**.

But it looks like it exists in microsoft bot framework **SDK v3**.

The following is the code that I am trying to implement on **SDK v4**.

```
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
  appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
  appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

// Middleware to check for OFFICE_365_TENANT_FILTER and only continue processing if it matches.
// If OFFICE_365_TENANT_FILTER is not specified, do nothing.

bot.use({
  botbuilder: function(session, next) {
    var targetTenant = typeof(process.env.OFFICE_365_TENANT_FILTER) !== "undefined" ? process.env.OFFICE_365_TENANT_FILTER : null;
    var currentMsgTenant = typeof(session.message.sourceEvent.tenant) !== "undefined" ? session.message.sourceEvent.tenant.id : null;
    if (targetTenant !== null) {
      if (targetTenant == currentMsgTenant) {
        next();
      }
      else {
        console.log("MS Teams: Attempted access from a different Office 365 tenant (" + currentMsgTenant + "): message rejected");
      }
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
  }
});
```

Could some one help in finding the alternative to get the **session.message.sourceEvent.tenant** in **SDKv4** ?

Comment: Are you trying to build a bot for  MS Teams? And, do you already have a bot built or are you starting from scratch? It looks like you are starting new.

Comment: Yes I am building for MS Teams.
I do have bot built already.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the issue.

Okay I got to know that SDKv4 is completely different pattern from SDKv3 and it can't be compared the way that I compared in the question.

However I got the information of the tenant using the turnContext which is the argument for each step like turnContext.activity.channelData.tenant.id.

This solved the problem.